# How to move from brute force algorithm to smart algorithms?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, brute-force, greedy, divide-and-conquer

when I am solving problems, I always use brute force to algorithms which always give time limit issue.
I really don't know what to do ?
how to change my approach from brute force algorithm to smart algorithms

for example I am solving this problem on hackerrank:

"Consider an array of integers, . We define the absolute difference between two elements,  and  (where ), to be the absolute value of .

Given an array of  integers, find and print the minimum absolute difference between any two elements in the array.

Input Format

The first line contains a single integer denoting  (the number of integers). 
The second line contains  space-separated integers describing the respective values of .

Constraints

```
2<n<2^5
10^-9<ai<10^9
```

Output Format
Print the minimum absolute difference between any two elements in the array.

Sample Input

```
3
3 -7 0
```

Sample Output

```
3
```

my approach is to subtract each element with with every element
and print the min difference but it is giving time limit issue

Comment: Hard to help when you didn't copy the question correctly or show any of your attempts

Comment: To the question in the tile there is unfortunately no general receipe. One has to be "smart". You can get some experience by studying algorithms and data structures.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have copied correctly

Comment: This sentence isn't complete... "We define the absolute difference between two elements, and (where ), to be the absolute value of ."

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort the array in ascending order.
2. Now check the difference between every two consecutive elements and minimise the difference.

   ```
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   int minDiff = arr[n - 1] - arr[0];
   for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
       int tmpDiff = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
       if (tmpDiff < minDiff) {
           minDiff = tmpDiff;
       }
   }
   ```

The simple observation is - when the array is sorted, for any element `arr[i]`, immediate smaller and larger elements will stay in left (`i - 1`th position) and right (`i + 1`th position) side respectively. There is no possibility to get smaller absolute difference with elements other than `arr[i - 1]` or `arr[i + 1]`. (why?)

This is a simple greedy problem. You have to practice more to come up with idea for such problem. After coming up with any idea, try to verify the correctness by ***proof by contradiction***, ***proof by induction***. Good luck!

#### Edit

Sorting will take `O(nlogn)` with some overhead for string comparison. And iterating to find the difference will take `O(n)`. So the time complexity will be `O(nlog n)` overall.

Your idea will take `O(n^2)` which is far slower as you are comparing each elements with each.

Comment: sorting array is another operation which will take time so won't sorting + finding minimum difference take more time than my code ?

Comment: @AaqibSoomro Check the update. I have got accepted with this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Brut force means that you need to do all the set of solutions possible in order to verify if your problem is solved or not.

To avoid doing a brut force you need yo find a way to reduce the set of solutions possible in order to have less solution to try.